# How to use POST to MySql with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, html, fetch-api

I'm trying to post data to the database using the Fetch API, PHP & SQL. It's not working, but I'm not sure where the issue is coming from.

The input which I want to post:

```
  <form  id="postData" action="api/postWords.php" onsubmit="submitForm(event, this)">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="values" id="WordValue">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="SEND POST">
    </form>
```

Fetch API, where I'm trying to post the form

```
   function submitForm(e, postData){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('postData').addEventListener('submit', postData);
    fetch('api/postWords.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      type: 'JSON',
      body: ({WordValue: postData.values.value})
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      //Success code goes here
      alert('form submited')
      .then(result => alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
    }).catch(function(err) {
      //Failure
      alert('Error')
    });
}
```

PHP file with SQL statement:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["WordValue"])) // prints out error if projectname is not set
{
    die();
}

require_once("db.php");

$status = 200; // OK
$Words = $_POST["WordValue"];

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $WordValue ); $i++ )
{
    $WordValue = $Words[$i];

    if ( !empty( $Words ) )
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO words (Words) VALUES ('$Words')");

        if ( !$result )
        {
            $status = 300; // OK
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $status = 301;
    }
}

echo json_encode( array('status'=>$status));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a second submit event listener, inside of the function that is already handling the form submit? (And _what_ you are trying to add as the callback function, does not make sense either. `postData` is the `this` you passed in from the calling context, so this will be the form element itself. Trying to add “a form” as an event handler, makes no sense.)

Comment: You have so many mistakes in your PHP code. You need to start over.